# Checking a string to see if it contains a substring

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
def contains_bitly_url(tweet):
    if tweet.startswith('http://bit.ly/'):
        return True
    elif tweet.find(' http://bit.ly/'):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

So I call this function using contains.bitly_url("hahahahahah") and it always return true. I ran it through a code visualizer and it is the "elif tweet.find(' http://bit.ly/'):" part that return true for some reason. Can anyone tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

[`str.find`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) returns -1 when a sub-string is not found, otherwise it returns the index of the string. So, here unless the string starts with `' http://bit.ly/'` `str.find` is always going to return a non-zero value(truthy). So, better check it against -1:

```
def contains_bitly_url(tweet):
    if tweet.startswith('http://bit.ly/'):
        return True
    elif tweet.find(' http://bit.ly/') != -1:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

You can simplify your function to:

```
def contains_bitly_url(tweet):
    return 'http://bit.ly/' in tweet
```

Comment: Thank you :) I didn't know it returned -1.

Answer (score 2):

`tweet.find(' http://bit.ly/')` is always True unless it returns `0`

```
def contains_bitly_url(tweet):
    return tweet.startswith('http://bit.ly/') or tweet.find(' http://bit.ly/') != -1
```

So use `tweet.find(' http://bit.ly/') != -1`

Also we can just return with an or as that will return `True` if either condition is `True` or `False` if both checks are are `False`

Or simply use in to see if the substring is `in` the main string as @MattDMo suggests:

```
def contains_bitly_url(tweet):
    return 'http://bit.ly/' in tweet
```

Comment: @MattDMo, yep did not even look at what they were really doing beyond the -1 issue